# How do you Partition On Elementary to Install Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, disk-management

I bought a brand new monitor and yet elementary won't recognize it. I'm planning to go back to Windows 8 but I need to partition the harddrive before doing so. What are the steps towards doing this so I can have a successful installation of Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install windows 8 and remove elementary  you do not need to create partitions from elementary.

If you want to create partition without Windows pre-installed on the hard drive, you can use a Windows installation disc to run Diskpart.

If nevertheless you insist on doing it from elementary you can use the application gparted included on elementary installer disk.

1. Use Loki Live-USB
2. Boot Elementary from that USB.
3. Open "Application" and run Gparted (There you can change your partitions)
4. Restart removing Live-USB
5. Install Windows 8

I understand that Microsoft will remove grub from master boot record with a clean install (I cannot check that as I only use linux in my computers).

Just in case this is not true try the following method:

Put a windows installation cd/dvd it in your optical drive or usb live installation in your USB and boot from it. On the installation screen where it asks you to install windows, click on Repair Your Computer on the lower left corner of your screen.
Now go to command prompt (It probably will show a window saying "Trying to repair windows automatically", close it) and type BootRec.exe /fixmbr
after it finishes GRUB is gone and you can now boot into windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

It gets a little more complicated because of grub. I would recommend you follow the instructions in the link below.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: I understand that @BoulDous wants to remove completely elementary. I can be wrong but I do not see a problem with grub on this circumstances. A clean Windows install should be enough. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/remove-linux-and-install-windows-10/ca092bd0-abff-495e-a62c-21e46a2eac9f

Comment: In any case I updated my answer to reflect your remarks regarding grub. I would appreciate feedback from @BoulDous to see if the master boot record (MBR) repair has been necessary. I would have tried that myself but... no copies of Windows around to test.  ;-)

Comment: That might be correct. I thought I had recalled doing this previously and having issues with the MBR because of grub. It could be as easy as installing windows normally.